# Are Dollhouse and Battlestar Galactica connected?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, dollhouse

I've noticed several references to Battlestar Galactica in the TV series Dollhouse. These include the sharing of Tahmoh Penikett and Jamie Bamber as cast members and at least one reference to Cylons (I believe Topher calls Bennet a Cylon at one point?)

Is there any connection between the two shows or are these just nods to another sci-fi show?

Comment: Haha ... Wondering if *The Big Bang Theory* might be related as well. How many times did Howard have Katee Sackhoff in the tub or the bed? Well, for that matter, I guess he had George Takei in the bed as well ... hmmmm.

Comment: @Paulster2 - BBT exists as the nexus universe of all SciFi/Geekdom universes.

Comment: @SystemDown Except for *Doctor Who.* Funny how **that** how doesn't seem to exist in BBT... ;)

Comment: @MeatTrademark actually I'm pretty certain Sheldon mentions loving to watch Dr. Who as a kid. Not sure if the reboot gets any love though.

Comment: The connection between *The A-Team* and the original BSG is arguably stronger (though tongue-in-cheek fourth-wall painting rather than anything that could be claimed as a "cannon" connection between plots).

Comment: Actors *play* characters. Actors themselves are not the characters...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Battlestar Galactica apparently exists in the world of Dollhouse, but only as a show. That would explain calling someone a Cylon.

Sharing actors is nothing new. Summer Glau is in Dollhouse, Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles and Firefly / Serenity (along with Alan Tudyk who also appeared in Dollhouse). This does not suggest that they are all in the same 'verse.  Adelle DeWitt (Olivia Williams) did not just have her husband Bruce Willis die, and Patton Oswalt's presence does not mean this is stand-up comedy. It's crazy how many of these people like to work together and get to on such fun (albeit usually short-lived) shows.

BSG is controlled by The Sci-Fi Channel (someone else can edit that) and Dollhouse was run by FOX. That's a bureaucratic problem with them existing in the same uiniverse, minus all the logistical.

Answer (score 2):

There are a million thematic links -- sleeper agents vs. cylons who think they're human.  the goo-bath you get in the attic vs. the resurrection ship.  the philosophical struggle between tech and real and "hybrid" as at the end of TDH with Anthony.  The good guys being bad guys being good guys until they're all sort of blended together and only your actions matter.

Comment: They are thematically similar,  but that's true for many unrelated scifi series. The question asks if they share any actual connection or if it's coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, yes *Dollhouse* is referencing *Battlestar Galactica* as one of many references.

First Joss Whedon is a [huge fan](https://www.thetvaddict.com/2008/07/16/exclusive-joss-whedon-talks-dollhouse-and-his-love-affair-with-battlestar-galactica/) of the *Battlestar Galactica* Re-imaged Series, he almost was [involved](https://www.google.com/search?q=joss%20whedon%20almost%20did%20battlestar&rlz=1CAQRFK_enUS722US722&oq=joss%20whedon%20almost%20did%20battlestar&aqs=chrome..69i57.8531j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in it!

> **You’re clearly a huge fan of BSG [BATTLESTAR GALACTICA]. Have you
>   talked to the creators?** Yeah, Ron [Ronald D. Moore] and I during the
>   writer’s strike spent some time together on the picket lines. I try
>   not to be too embarrassing though.
>
> **Must be a nice pat on the back for them to know what a fan you are of
>   the show?** Well I’m not the only one, but yeah I’m pretty passionate
>   about the show. I stole Tahmoh [Penikett] and I’ll steal again!

There are some out of universe connections most notably **Consulting Producer and writer Jane Espenson**, who wrote a few *Battlestar Galctica* episodes and was given producer credits on later seasons.

There are also *Battlestar Galactica* **directors** Rob Hardy, Allen Kroeker, and Marita Grabiak.

And prominent *Battlestar Galactica* **actors** Micheal Hogan, Tahmoh Penikett, Mark Sheppard, *Dollhouse* special guest stars like Jamie Bamber.

**Along with some story allusions/references**

[The Hollow Man](http://dollhouse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hollow_Men) - Allusion

> Aside from "The Dark Phoenix Saga," Mellie's story was also influenced
>   by Whedon's professed love of Battlestar Galactica, wherein a Cylon
>   had fallen in love with a human and had to choose between what she
>   knew to be the truth (that she was a machine) and what she felt to be
>   real (that she was a human being).

[Ghost](http://dollhouse.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost) - Reference

> Gabriel refers to Edward James Olmos, an American actor and director
>   best known for his role in the remake of Battlestar Galactica TV
>   series. Joss Whedon is apparently a big fan and Tahmoh Penikett
>   appeared in the show as a series regular.